# LSTM language model for cloze tasks

Tags: natural-language, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am looking for any papers or suggestions of how one may perform training and inference for [cloze tasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloze_test) (fill in the blanks) with multiple blanks in the sentence.
In the case of just 1 blank, using an LSTM from both directions would be a good idea, but what about cases with multiple blanks?

```
After a brief pursuit, the ________ was caught and arrested by the ______.
```

Update: Some things I have considered are using [Seq2Seq](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq), but there is no easy way for a selection of one of the blank words to affect the selection of the other. For example, a input like `_____ and ______` should be either answered with `cats and dogs` or `apples and oranges` but not `cats and oranges`.